# ListBox binding from ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, binding, listbox

How to bind from `ListBox` `ItemTemplate` correctly in the below example. I'd like to show each `ListBoxItem` to appear on Background color specified in the Tag.

```
<ListBox>
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Background="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <ListBox.Items>
         <ListBoxItem Content="1" Tag="Blue" />
         <ListBoxItem Content="2" Tag="Green"/>
         <ListBoxItem Content="3" Tag="Red"/>
    </ListBox.Items>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need **`ItemContainerStyle`** and not **`ItemTemplate`**.

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Tag,
                                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.Items>
        <ListBoxItem Content="1" Tag="Blue" />
        <ListBoxItem Content="2" Tag="Green"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="3" Tag="Red"/>
    </ListBox.Items>
</ListBox>
```

---

ItemTemplate is used to represent bound data on UI but in your case you have already defined your data inside ListBoxItem. So, having ItemTemplate doesn't make sense here. Moreover, ***you can simply set Background on ListBoxItem itelf instead of setting it in Tag***.

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Items>
        <ListBoxItem Content="1" Background="Blue" />
        <ListBoxItem Content="2" Background="Green"/>
        <ListBoxItem Content="3" Background="Red"/>
    </ListBox.Items>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: When I have a theme applied the above doesn't work still. But adjusting then ItemContainerStyle <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}" /> it works/overrides the theme style.